# When would you use hasOwnProperty on an array?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have just seen an example where the code is as follows:

```
var schemaSet:Array = currentScope();
if (schemaSet.hasOwnProperty("current"))
    schema = schemaSet["current"];
```

I have never seen this before. I checked the [as3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Array()) docs and didn't find any information on it. Note: This code is from SchemaManager.currentSchema() written by an Adobe employee.

When and where would you use this? Is this better than or equivalent to:

```
if (schemaSet.indexOf("current")!=-1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of data:

- Normal arrays, which contain only values and the keys are numeric, starting from 0.
- And there are also objects, where every element has a string (it can also be a number too) key.

If you want to check if an array contains a value, you will go with .indexOf() method.

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

if (myArray.indexOf("a") > -1) return true;
```

If you want to check if an object has an element with a certain key, then you will go for hasOwnProperty() method.

```
var myObject = {a: "letter a", b: "letter b"}

if (myObject.hasOwnProperty("a")) return true;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought but I forgot to mention the code sample is from Adobe Flex SDK written by an Adobe employee. So if the array contains strings then `hasOwnProperty()` is same as `indexOf()>-1`?

Comment: Not really. indexOf() will look only in values, and hasOwnProperty() will look only in keys. So depending on what you want to check you will choose the appropriate method.